# Forçar o redirecionamento para ambiente HTTPS

Tags: htaccess, ssl, https

Como forçar o redirecionamento para o ambiente com HTTPS com HTACCESS?
Preciso que o código seja adaptado ao que já tenho:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente inserir essas linhas :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ HTTPS://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```