# Como redirecionar para uma pasta e HTTPS em simultâneo?

Tags: apache, htaccess, amazon-aws, elastic-beanstalk

Tenho um site http://meusite.pt que é um [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) de http://minhamaquina.amazon.com, onde está o site alojado. Só que eu precisava que fosse redirecionado para a pasta `meusite` do minha maquina da amazon, ou seja, http://minhamaquina.amazon.com/meusite, mas que se mantenha apenas visível http://meusite.pt.

Eu consegui isso com esta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36972084

```
RewriteEngine on 

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?meusite.pt$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/meusite/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /meusite/$1 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?meusite.pt$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ meusite/ [L]
```

O meu problema agora é que preciso de redirecionar também de http para https, ou seja se eu digitar http://meusite.pt ele redirecionará para https://meusite.pt que terá de ir buscar o conteúdo a http://minhamaquina.amazon.com/meusite.

O certificado está em `meusite.pt`.

É possível fazer isso com o `.htaccess`? Como?

[EDIT]

Adicionei as linhas (comentadas) da pergunta que foi indicada como duplicata, mas fica em loop:

> This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: Olha se é isso http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175119/for%C3%A7ar-o-redirecionamento-para-ambiente-https/175123#175123

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Redirecionar site https para http](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15514/redirecionar-site-https-para-http)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52294/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-localhost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri uma forma de fazer no SOen que resolveu o meu problema, não é bem uma resposta ao que eu perguntei, mas é a solução do problema, que é basicamente usar as linhas que me foram sugeridas nos comentários num ficheiro de configuração da amazon como podemos ver [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38751749/1817673).

Em resumo da resposta basta colocar um ficheiro [`.config` na diretoria `.ebextensions` do projeto](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) o seguinte:

```
files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            RewriteEngine On
            <If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
            RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
            </If>
```

Que ao fazer deploy da aplicação adiciona essa regra ao Apache do Elastic Beanstalk.